# No puedo utilizar "transition: opacity 1s 0s ease;"

Tags: css

Básicamente no me deja utiliza el transition: opacity en CSS, al mover el mouse hacia el objetivo, la idea es que tenga opacity 0, y al colocar el puntero sobre el objeto, haya una transición para que opacity pase a 1, el problema es que pasa a 1, pero sin la transición.

```
.nav li ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s 0s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s 0s ease;
}

.nav li:hover > ul
{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Pista: revisá [las propiedades que se pueden animar en CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es con `opacity`, sino con `display`. Sucede que la propiedad `display` *no es animable*.

En [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) (en la versión en inglés), puedes revisar esto yendo a la página relacionada a la propiedad, en la sección *Formal definition* > *Animation type*. En el caso de [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#formal_definition), verás que dice *Not animatable* (no animable).

Comment: fuck, entonces cagué, xq si saco los display se me arruina todo me parece, bueno, voy a tener q usar keyframes, cosa que no quería jajajaja, graciass

Comment: Hay estrategias y estrategias, algunas "lindas", otras no tanto... Buscando un poquito más podés encontrar alternativas. Fuerzas, algo saldrá :)

Comment: Jajajajja muchas graciass, si, con insistencia todo sale, saludos!